# Getting Unable to get property 'undefined' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with my code from javascript.  When I hit the button the function runs, but nothing happens on the screen.  I went into the development tools for IE, and noticed that when I ran the script I got the following: Unable to get property 'undefined' of undefined or null reference.  This stems from a else statement in the script of:

```
function doSearch(){
    var selectedItem = document.getElementsByName("engines").selectedIndex;
    if (selectedItem == -1)
        alert("You must select a search engine.");
    else
        location.href = document.getElementsByName("engines").option[selectedItem].value + document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
}
```

I believe the code in the html to be right, but it just doesn't seem to work.  For example in the select list options for Google I have:

```
<option value="http://www.google.com/search?q=">Google</option>
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably the element you are trying to access isnt present in DOM

Comment: your function is searching for an element with the NAME "engines", make sure you have an element with that name.

Comment: method `getElementsByName` returns an array, not a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the select is

```
<select name="engines">
```

then you need

```
document.getElementsByName("engines")[0].selectedIndex
```

and

```
location.href = document.getElementsByName("engines")[0].option[selectedItem].value ...
```

since getElement**s**ByName returns a collection

If the select is

```
<select id="engines">
```

then you need

```
document.getElementById("engines").selectedIndex
```

Additionally I would use

```
if (selectedItem < 1)
```

if I had a "please select" since the user could select the first option

---

Here is how I would likely code it (NOTE: Google does not work in an iFrame, but bing does)

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("engines").onchange=function() {
    var engine = this.value;
    if (engine) {
      location.href = engine.replace("@",document.getElementById("searchTerm").value);
    } 
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="searchTerm" type="text" />
<select id="engines">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com/search?q=@">Google</option>
  <option value="https://www.bing.com/search?q=@">Bing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes the select is <select name="engines"> I then have about 5 options. and then a </select> tag.  So in this case you are saying that my variable for selectedItem is wrong?

Comment: And for the value. Both needs the [0] for the first select named that on the page. If there are more, [1] will access the second select named engines

Comment: Ok I got it working using both your new example and by your explanation above that.  While I was still having the error at first I just added some error checking values in there so it would print out what was being shown and I was able to see what I was doing wrong.  You were right with your explanation, but I also had a typo that was hindering the whole thing.